# Get distinct records with counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a table with `personid` and `msg` colums.

```
personid, msg
--------------
 1,      'msg1'
 2,      'msg2'
 2,      'msg3'
 3,      'msg4'
 1,      'msg2'
```

I want to get total `msg` for each `personid`.
I am trying this query:

```
select distinct personid, count(*)
FROM mytable;
```

I also tried this query

```
select distinct personid, count(msg)
FROM mytable;
```

But not getting actual result.
I want this result for above data:

```
id, count
--------
1,   2
2,   2
3,   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. So try this query:

```
SELECT personid, COUNT(msg) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY personid
ORDER BY personid;
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75892/1)

> `GROUP BY` lets you use aggregate functions, like `AVG()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`,
>   `SUM()`, `COUNT()` etc while `DISTINCT` just removes duplicates.