# SQL - Identify Distinct Values Including Count For ALL Columns In A Table

Tags: sql

I want to be able to identify the distinct values including a count of the value for each column in a table.

I reviewed - [Get distinct records with counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330686/get-distinct-records-with-counts?rq=1)

And it shows me how to do this for an individual column and works great.  However, I have a table with over 600 columns, and coding each column would be incredibly time consuming.

Is there a way to code my sql where I could get these same results for all columns in a table, without having to individually input each column?

So to use the example from the link:

```
personid, msg  
-------------
1, 'msg1'  
2, 'msg2'  
2, 'msg3'  
3, 'msg4'  
1, 'msg2'
```

My results would be:

```
personid, count | msg, count
-----------------------------
1,         2 |       msg1,    1  
2,         2 |       msg2,    2  
3,         1 |       msg3,    1  
_, _         |       msg4,    1
```

Is this possible?  I've tried getting at it using distincts and wildcards (*) but no luck.

Apologize if this isn't detailed enough, this is my first post and I'm no SQL expert, and Googling hasn't found an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: You can get the `personid, count` as one result and `msg, count` as another result using two different queries

Comment: I would write a quick utility that constructs and outputs the query you need (as a string) based on the schema information of the table. But you need to understand where the schema info exists for your DB type.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it convinient, but you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    personid int,
    message nvarchar(max)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT 1, 'msg1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'msg2' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'msg3' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'msg4' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'msg2';
GO

SELECT 
    isnull(t1.rn, t2.rn) as rn, 
    t1.personid as personid, t1.cnt as personid_cnt, 
    t2.message as message, t2.cnt as message_cnt
FROM
    (SELECT personid, count(*) as cnt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by personid) as rn 
        FROM #temp GROUP BY personid) t1
    FULL JOIN
    (SELECT message, count(*) as cnt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by message) as rn 
        FROM #temp GROUP BY message) t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY rn

DROP table #temp;
```

result:

```
rn  personid    personid_cnt    message message_cnt
1   1   2   msg1    1
2   2   2   msg2    2
3   3   1   msg3    1
4   NULL    NULL    msg4    1
```